# how can i get the recorded file length in ionic?

Tags: audio, ionic-framework, media

I am using ionic cordova media plugin to record audio from the user's phone. Once recorded i get the file to play and everything is fine. I just want to get the duration of the file and when i play the recorded file i want to show the minutes::seconds of the file being played. How do i do that?

```
record_audio(){

    this.file.startRecord();
    this.recording = true;


    /*
    let record_opt: CaptureAudioOptions = { limit: 1 };

    this.mediacapture.captureAudio(record_opt).then(
        (data: MediaFile[]) => alert('audio recorded'),
         (err: CaptureError)=> alert('cannot record')

    );
    */

}

cancel_record(){

    this.file.release();
    this.show_record_div = false;
    this.recordedfile_available = false;

}

stop_recording(){

    this.file.stopRecord();
    this.recording = false;
    this.recordedfile_available = true;
    //this.filelength = this.file.getDuration();

}


play_recorded(){

    this.file.play();

}


stop_playing(){

    this.file.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
let duration = this.file.getDuration();
  console.log(duration);
// get current playback position
file.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
    console.log(position);
});
```

Comment: thx @enRaiser for the reply.. i did that but it only show -1 the first time i record. the second time i record then can see the duration.